# Manim Example Scenes Don't Run

Tags: manim

I can't run any example in manim and no error shows, it just gives me a blank line in the cmd and if i try to run it from the folder it just opens up the cmd and closes quickly. I have spent days trying to figure this out. Anyone know the reason? I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENMyFGmq5OA&list=PL2B6OzTsMUrwo4hA3BBfS7ZR34K361Z8F)
You can learn more
[Can manim be used in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60691915/can-manim-be-used-in-pycharm/62492705#62492705)